# UIVisualEffectView glitches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I'm trying to create a super thin UIVisualEffectView (2 pixels tall) with a blur effect.  I'm attaching it to the bottom of a collection view cell.  The issue on scrolling the effect view flickers between a black color and the blur (sometimes it will remain black when I stop scrolling).  When I increase the height to 3 pixels, it behaves normally.

Is there a limitation on how small I can make a UIVisualEffectView before it behaves unpredictably?  If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you making it 2 **pixels** or 2 **points** tall? At that size, do you really notice a difference between using a translucent view vs a "blur" view?

Comment: i'm making it 2 points tall.  it's not too noticeable but you can tell

Comment: Without testing, I'd say it's very possible that 2-point tall `UIVisualEffectView` might not work well. Try using a larger view and masking it to your desired height.

Comment: masking didn't even cross my mind.  this worked.  thanks for the feedback

Comment: Glad it worked... I went ahead and posted it as an answer, for other folks who may come across this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment...

`UIVisualEffectView` with blur effect uses adjacent pixels to generate the *blur* ... using a very small (in this case, 2-points-tall) view **apparently** causes the issue.

To avoid that, use a slightly larger `UIVisualEffectView` and mask it to the desired 2-points height.